# having problems understanding twitter API (unexpected token: package)

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm following a tutorial (http://davidcrowley.me/?p=435) and I cannot get the code to work.

I have set up my twitter application and have the consumer key, consumer secret, access token, and access token secret.
I believe the problem is within the way I've loaded the libraries, so an explanation of how to load the twitter4j library would be great. I don't know if I need to load the entire .zip? Ive been trying to teach myself but I am feeling very defeated.

```
package com.crowley.simplestream;

import twitter4j.FilterQuery;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class SimpleStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("****");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("****");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("****");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("****");

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                User user = status.getUser();

                // gets Username
                String username = status.getUser().getScreenName();
                System.out.println(username);
                String profileLocation = user.getLocation();
                System.out.println(profileLocation);
                long tweetId = status.getId(); 
                System.out.println(tweetId);
                String content = status.getText();
                System.out.println(content +"\n");

            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
        FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

        String keywords[] = {"ireland"};

        fq.track(keywords);

        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.filter(fq);  

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us error message\exception\stack trace... at least something what describes your problem.

Comment: What saroff said + You should log what is coming in through `onException`! Might be helpful for debugging (among other things).

Comment: If you believe that is the library, you need to load the ".jar" file, but it depends on which system (windows, linux) and which method (command line, an IDE) are you using

Comment: How are you writing your code? What editor are you using? Are you using a basic editor and the command line, or are you using eclipse or netbeans, or are you using the Processing IDE?

Comment: "error on 'package," tab, line 1

im using mac with processing IDE

im using tutorial that i linked too. im really just trying to get the code to work so i can start my project.

Comment: Thank you for the responses and thank you for baring with me! like i said i am a noob, but your help is making my day!!